# React.Children does not detect when child(ren) is null

Tags: reactjs

I have read the various related issues on this subject, but none of them provide me with a solution.

my child is defined as follows

```
const RevocationHandler = ({ onClose = noop }) => {
  const revocation = useRevocationContext();
  const [isOpen, toggleOpen] = useState(false);

  if (revocation.onRevoke == null) {
    console.log('I am null');
    return null;
  }

  function handleButtonClick (evt: React.MouseEvent): void {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    toggleOpen(true);
  }

  function handleClose () {
    toggleOpen(false);
    onClose();
  }

  if (!isOpen) {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={handleButtonClick}
      >
        Revoke
      </button>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Modal onClose={handleClose} useTransparency={true}>
        <RevocationForm onCancel={handleClose} />
      </Modal>
    );
  }
};
```

Please note that it's using Context to retrieve a callback function, and if that function is undefined, it should return null.

The parent is defined as such:

```
<ActionMenu>
  <RevocationHandler />
</ActionMenu>
```

I would like the `ActionMenu` not to render if all (in this case only 1) children are null.

I have tried various variations of the following code:

```
React.Children
  .toArray(children)
  .filter((child) => React.isValidElement(child))
  .length
```

With `count`, with `filter`, with `map`, whatever I try, at this moment of the execution React tells me I have 1 child. Yet, when things run, I do get the `I am null` console log:

[image]

As well as nothing rendered:

[image]

My question is, how do I properly detect that my Child will be null in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have gone with the "React" way. It breaks encapsulation as it leaks concerns where it shouldn't, and eventually I still read the `Children.count` option (which is provided by React). And now it works. Less cleanly.

**inAnotherFileThatShouldNotNeedToKnow.ts**:

```
<ActionMenu>
  {canRevoke && <RevocationHandler />}
</ActionMenu>
```

**ActionMenu.ts**:

```
if (React.Children.count(children) === 0) {
  return null;
}
```

It's a pity that there is no better way to know that a child will return `null`, when things like `React.Children.toArray` does filter `null` children for you, but I can move on with my life as it serves my purpose: the `ActionMenu` is smart enough to not render when it has nothing to render.

Don't just believe in React dogma, people.

Answer (score 1):

At the first place what do you mean saying *I would like the ActionMenu not to render* ? If ActionMenu consists only of children and every child is null then nothing will be rendered anyway...

At second place that is the main ideology of react - all data goes from parents to children, so yopu can not rely on anything which children will render, then everything is upsidedown - children should depend on parent information...

So the approach is basically wrong i guess.

Comment: To your first point, correct, this is the last picture in my question: nothing is there, so essentially, no child to render.

To your second point, indeed, data goes for parent to child, or even better you can make components work on their own and avoid trees that pass information down the line of many many components. Context is helpful in that regard. Now the issue is that if all your children are null, you cannot know that it seems, yet, they are null at render time. It's not entirely wrong to say: do not render if you have nothing to render.

Comment: My real problem is that `React.Children` manipulation returns that there is something, when there will be nothing.

Comment: @Moustachiste, no, your real problem is basically wrong approach to architecture... children returns you object before rendering so you can not know the result and you will never know it in parent by the nature of things

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, data should flow from parent to child. You can move context checks to the parent component such that you have control over whether to render the children or not.

The child component will take care of its core functionality (like to show a modal on click of a button) and the parent component will decide based on checks when to render the child components.

```js
const RevocationHandler = ({ onClose = noop }) => {
  const [isOpen, toggleOpen] = useState(false);

  function handleButtonClick (evt: React.MouseEvent): void {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    toggleOpen(true);
  }

  function handleClose () {
    toggleOpen(false);
    onClose();
  }

  if (!isOpen) {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={handleButtonClick}
      >
        Revoke
      </button>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Modal onClose={handleClose} useTransparency={true}>
        <RevocationForm onCancel={handleClose} />
      </Modal>
    );
  }
};
```

```js
const ActionMenu = ({children}) => {

   // you can add a check here if children should be rendered
   const revocation = useRevocationContext();
   if (revocation.onRevoke == null) {
    console.log('I am null');
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
        ....
        {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: That is not working in terms of separation of concerns. The ActionMenu is just a shallow wrapper that renders whatever children we give it. But it shouldn't be concerned about what those children are and what their business concerns are either.

Comment: _**But it shouldn't be concerned about what those children are and what their business concerns are either**_, - Right, but you need _**I would like the ActionMenu not to render if all (in this case only 1) children are null.**_  so according to your current architecture parent should be aware of children and what they render.

Comment: and if ActionMenu is just a shallow wrapper and all children are null then anyways it won't render anything

Comment: In my opinion there is a difference between caring about the internal rules that make it hide and show, and knowing that there is something or there isn't. `React.Children.toArray` has the ability to filter `null`, which is essentially what I was trying to achieve. It seems I am hitting a wall and these 2 answers are more about semantics than actual solutions.

Comment: > then anyways it won't render anything. Then that's exactly why I am asking a question on stackoverflow innit?